# Creating a "popup" side menu in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an idea for my application, but I don't how to go about implementing it. Basically, I have a chat application, but you're able to tell the application whether it's a happy or sad message. I drew it out to hopefully make it easier for you to understand. Can anyone provide me with any insight on creating this kind of effect?

### **Step one (Hidden):**

---

[image]

---

### **Step two (User clicks face):**

---

[image]

---

### **Step three (user clicks face and it disappears):**

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Try this library.

Tutorial here - http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Library here - https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use QuickActionController. Find the source of the Control at https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction.

You just need to shift the position of display towards the right at quickaction UI class. Your requirement will be met.